# Browser Based Speed Test vs Client Based

Tags: networking, connection, network-adapter, speedtest

Update: Originally, I thought there was a difference in the browser-based speed test results because I missed the difference in units between them and my client network monitor. At first this difference made me suspect the various jumps along the way to my target ip. But I but I held out suspicion that the network monitor basically confirms that I could reach my target speeds, not that I can sustain them--the same thing a browser-based speed test does--and that there may still be an issue with my speeds. It turns out that my particular examples are apples and oranges. BitMeter doesn't test speed directly. I does tell you where you top out, but this metric isn't necessarily useful here. What matters is what speeds you can sustain. It turned out that a third party ISP had a modem in my building that was interfering with traffic. A line tech came out today, removed the modem from the network and everything is working swimmingly.

I stream video from my computer. My upload speed determines the bitrate or quality of the video I can stream. I pay for 20 megabits/second upload from my ISP. When I use their [speed test](http://speedtest.xfinity.com/) it tells me I get about 15Mb/s up. But this is much higher than what I can actually stream. My stream becomes unstable anywhere above 2Mb. This is my real world ceiling. OBS, the software I use to stream, confirms that the optimal bitrate for my stream should be about 2000 kilobits. I can further verify this with a client-based tool like [BitMeter OS](https://codebox.net/pages/bitmeteros). The image below was captured during an Xfinity browser-based speed test. It demonstrates that despite an upload result of ~15Mb/s, my upload speed never exceeds 2.72Mb/s.

[image]

In short, there is a discrepancy between what many browser-based speed tests report and what my real world speeds are. I recognize that there are multiple layers here. For example, the platform I use to stream may be having server issues that limit my upload. This, of course, is easily diagnosed by asking other streamers in my region if they're experiencing issues. Futhermore, client-based tools seem to verify the upload ceiling observed while streaming, showing the same rate to independent servers.

Something very interesting is that I upgraded my package with my ISP to see if I'd get better upload rates. While there was a definite increase in my upload rates on the browser-based speed test, there was no change at all in the rate I can actually stream at or in the rate reported by BitMeter OS.

How can this be? What about some browser-based speed tests can cause them to estimate upload rates much higher than rates reported by client-based diagnostics or observed real-world upload rates?

Again, I understand there are multiple layers at work here. For example, when downloading files you will likely not reach the speeds your package advertises. But this is a limitation of the servers you're downloading from. In this case, my peers and colleagues upload rates are easily upward of 10Mb/s on the same server I stream to.

In short, I'm looking for an explanation of how I'm limited to ~2Mb/s despite a browser-based speed test reporting a rate of ~15Mb/s. I need to speak effectively to my ISP but cannot so long as I don't understand how their browser-based test can be so inaccurate.

Comment: Your units are not matching up MB and Mb are not the same typically.  Dslreports has a more truthful speed test

Comment: Might help ignore you provide which Xfinity plan you have specifically and a screenshot of the units Comcast advertises

Comment: Wow, I can believe I missed that BitMeter's units were in bytes. So according to it I am reaching upwards of 20 Mbps. However, I cannot stream at that rate. Not even close. This finding complicates things. I suppose the title should be "Speed Tests vs Real World Speeds."

Comment: Your upload to a specific destination may be limited by any link along the way; just because your ISP gets you 20Mbps to the first hop does not mean there is no congestion or slow links between you and where you want to get to...